# Redirect all pages to home and remove .php extension in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to Redirect 301 all my pages to my home in the .htaccess file.
But I would like also:

- Remove the .php extension at the end of the URL of the contact page.
- Keep my contact page like that example.com/contact (without .php extension and with no redirect to home)
- Don't redirect my css, jpg, js files to home

Could you help me please?

Comment: what have you tried? show some code!

Comment: Someone please ?